# Why isn't the archive being sent via urllib.request?

Tags: python

I am trying to send an archive to Telegram through urllib, I get an error about the connection being closed without a response.

```
RemoteDisconnected('Remote end closed connection without response')
```

I need to do it exactly with standard python tools, that is, lib requests and others will not work.

What am I doing wrong?

```
from os import stat
from urllib import request, parse

token = ""
user_id = 0

with open("files.zip", "rb") as f:

    headers = {'Content-Type': 'application/zip',  'Content-Length': stat("files.zip").st_size}

    r = request.Request(
        url=f"https://api.telegram.org/bot{token}/sendDocument?chat_id={user_id}",
        data=parse.urlencode({"document": f}).encode("utf-8"),
        headers=headers
    )
    request.urlopen(r)

file.close()
```